# Solving a matrix for the system of equations with boundaries

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the system of equations
$$-X_{k-1}+2X_k-X_{k-1}=λX_k$$
for $ k=1,2,...,N, N∈\Bbb N $ with boundary conditions $X_0=X_{N+1}=0$(here $X_k$ are scalars).

a) Write down a $N×N$ matrix C such that the above equations are equivalent to $CX=λX$.

b) Find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of C (hint: look for eigenvectors that are trigonometric functions of k)

Before solving for the matrix C, it seems to me that X is just a zero vector. Since $X_0=X_{N+1}=0$ and $X_{k+1}=(2-λ)X_k-X_{k-1}$, $X_1=0, X_2=(2-λ)*0+0=0$ and same for other X. It would not make any sense to solve for C if X is just a zero vector. Am I understanding this wrong? If so, any idea to solve for C?

If we just consider nontrivial case, I solve the C as $$ \begin{bmatrix}
        λ & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
-1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots& 0 \\
        0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & \cdots& 0 \\
\vdots & & & \ddots&&&\vdots\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & λ\\
        \end{bmatrix} $$

For the b) part, if we solved for matrix C, since CX=λX, isn't that λ should be one of the eigenvalues and X should be one of the eigenvector?

I tried to solve eigenvalues and eigenvectors by using det(C-λ'I)=0 where λ' is the eigenvalue for C.

Therefore, another eigenvalue for C is 2. Then I tried to solve for the corresponding eigenvector and it is not a trigonometric function.

Any ideas or comments are greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Is the lambda in CX = LX, the same lambda as the one in the first equation?

Comment: Is lambda scalar?

Comment: Is the N in k = 1..N, the same N for the dimensions of C?

Comment: While the "endpoints" $X_0 = X_{N+1} = 0$, the intermediate values $X_1,\ldots, X_N$ are unknowns (and will not necessarily be zero).  The system of equations is homogeneous, so trivially it will have a trivial (zero) solution, but the goal here is to formulate the system and find those values $\lambda$ for which there are non-trivial solutions (i.e. the eigenvalues $\lambda$ of matrix $C$).

Comment: I just assume that λ is the same as the one in the first equation since there are no other information specified in the question.

Answer (score 0):

We would need to show that

$\exists C \in {\mathbb R} ^{n \times n}$

$ \ni CX_k =X_{k-1} $

$ \forall k \in \{  1..N \}$